# Node JS installation - ReferenceError: node is not defined issue

Tags: node.js

Recently , I have installed nodejs in my window 64 bit system ,When I try to check with   command  node -v it should show version of it but it shows error

```
> node -v
ReferenceError: node is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:441:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
>
```

I don't understand the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: formatting improvements

Answer (score 1):

You are inside **Node REPL**. Type **process.exit(1)** and then type **node -v**

Answer (score 0):

You can check version in two ways, in your bash shell or DOS shell with "node -v" which display something like this :

[image]

Or directly in the node shell using process.version. You get this error cuz you type "node -v" in the node shell

[image]